# Debezium Server only logging schema changes and not logging data changes

Tags: debezium, change-data-capture, debezium-server

I am currently trying to standup debezium server to track data changes in a MySQL database. I have successfully set up the debezium-server project in Ubuntu and successfully connected it to my database. It is able to notice the when I make changes to the schema of the database but it does not seem to notice when I make data changes. For example, if I make a standard ALTER TABLE statement, it notices and logs that change. How ever if I make a standard UPDATE statement and alter the data in a row, it does not notice or log that change. Below is my configuration in the debezium-server/conf/application.properties file. Any ideas on how to get this to see the data changes would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
debezium.sink.type=rabbitmq
debezium.sink.rabbitmq.connection.host=192.168.0.176
debezium.sink.rabbitmq.connection.port=5672
debezium.sink.rabbitmq.connection.username=test
debezium.sink.rabbitmq.connection.password=test
debezium.source.connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
debezium.source.offset.storage.file.filename=data/offsets.dat
debezium.source.offset.flush.interval.ms=0
debezium.source.database.hostname=192.128.0.155
debezium.source.database.port=3306
debezium.source.database.user=debTest
debezium.source.database.password=password
debezium.source.database.dbname=myDb
debezium.source.database.allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
debezium.source.database.server.id=1
debezium.source.topic.prefix=tutorial
debezium.source.schema.history.internal=io.debezium.storage.file.history.FileSchemaHistory
debezium.source.schema.history.internal.file.filename=mylog
debezium.source.schema.include.list=manufacturers
quarkus.log.console.json=false
```

I am expecting all row level changes to be picked up and logged by debezium. However only schema level changes are being logged.

Comment: Unless you add trace logging, you won't necessarily see anything logged for a DML event in the connector logs but you should see an event in your sink.  Have you confirmed that the data is on the sink side?